# How to not have my questions closed or downvoted?

Tags: support, down-votes

So far I have only [asked four questions](https://politics.stackexchange.com/users/2291/pgpb-padilla?tab=questions) on this site and it seems that I consistently ask bad questions, though personally I think they are really interesting questions and maybe even good questions.

Is is that I'm really that bad at asking questions or is it just a fact that most interesting questions (at least interesting to me) are bound to be controversial?

I have gone through the [help guide](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) but I'm still unable to edit my questions in a way that they can be taken seriously.

For example, take my latest question: [Is there any correlation between gender inequality and women choosing making porn for a living?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/8373/2291)

All I needed when I asked the question was some pointers to literature about the relationship between gender inequality and making porn for a living.

- I didn't ask for opinions on the subject. I got opinions anyway.
- I think the question is not open-ended. It must have a definite answer, if there's any literature about the topic then the answer would be a pointer to such literature, if no one knows any literature then it should just stay there, inactive. On the contrary I got down votes and other users rambling in the comments section.
- After being down-voted, I requested feedback in the comments but I got no answer at all that would help me improve the question.

So I all have now is more questions:

- Is there a more appropriate site to ask questions [like those four](https://politics.stackexchange.com/users/2291/pgpb-padilla?tab=questions)?
- How would you edit any of those questions so that it is answerable given the format in this site?

Comment: Did you seriously expect a question about *porn* to be a good question?! Do you really think people that do this kind of stuff *chose* to do it?!

Comment: @Bregalad The gender inequality question has problems, but being about porn isn't one of them. There's absolutely no reason at all why a question about porn can't be a good one (assuming, of course, it somehow relates to politics).

Comment: @Bregalad - yes, many do. Just because you can't imagine people doing something doesn't mean other people find it equally bad. I would be more open to being in porn than being a salesperson if those 2 were my only choices, FWIW - due to acute lack of talent to sell anything or convince people; and distaste for interacting with wetware.

Answer (score 4):

[Is there any correlation between gender inequality and women choosing making porn for a living?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/8373/101)

The question is fascinating, but off topic, as it's not really about politics. The data you are looking for *may* influence policy decisions, however for the question to be on topic it would actually have to be about the policy decisions, or at the very least about the processes that lead to those decisions.

Furthermore, Stack Exchange sites are not search engines, requests for external resources rarely fare well. You might get lucky once in a while, but in general if your question is of the "is there a book, study, website, etc" variety you should expect down and close votes.

You could of course remove the explicit requests for external resources, and focus on the actual question ("Is there any correlation between gender inequality and women choosing making porn for a living?"). This would be a good edit, but I'm afraid the question would still be off topic.

[Why is there so much fuss about an internet “fast lane” for a privileged few?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/7672/why-is-there-so-much-fuss-about-an-internet-fast-lane-for-a-privileged-few)

Again, technically, this is off topic. However it's main issue is that "why suddenly everyone goes crazy" is unanswerable. We can discuss it for hours, but that's really not what this site is for.

This one also doesn't fit the general Stack Exchange philosophy & format, so I'm afraid there isn't a site where we could move it.

[What are the main obstacles for implementing a Resource Based Economy as proposed by Jacque Fresco?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/2416/101)

This one is open, and answered. Not much to discuss here.

[Pros/Cons of anonymity in a modern democracy?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/2415/101)

The close reason picked isn't the more suitable one; "too broad" would better explain the issues with the question than "primarily opinion-based".

Nothing inherently wrong with questions asking for a list of things, however the site was build with questions with a limited set of self contained answers in mind. Lists of things simply don't fit the site's format: Their answers tend to be equally valid, which breaks the answer evaluation process ("Good answers are voted up and rise to the top").

---

Further reading:

- [What topics can I ask about here?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)
- [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: I must say I fully disagree with #4 - both the original closure AND your evaluation. It's absolutely NOT opinion based, but it also isn't really overly broad. At the point of closure, there were only 2 answers (after a fairly long time being opened) that were of any reasonable quality, and no hint that more would be forthcoming to the point that answer evaluation process would fail. Merely the fact that the question is phrased as a list is merely a possibility that it may generate list-type answers, but in no way a guarantee.

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​@DVK Your own answer there starts by discussing the vagueness of the question: "First of all, you didn't specify whether you're interested in anonymity of voting or anonymity of opinion expression. Those may have somewhat different reasons" - That said, the question may very well be salvageable with a few edits. The "pros/cons" phrasing is a later addition, I'd start by removing it. Phrasing matters, think of every new user who'll come upon the question and think "Oh, I have a pro to add, yay!". Unfortunately not everyone can look past the wording and focus at the core question.

Comment: the way I approach it is "too board" == several questions in one, where several >>2. This one was flawed (2 questions in one) but not more broad than that, IMHO.